# Derivative of a Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis

To prove $$\Gamma '(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x-1} \ln t \> dt \quad \quad x>0$$

I.e. why can we put the derivative inside the integral? We have

$$\frac{\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)}{h}=\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x-1} \left(\frac{t^h-1}{h}\right) dt$$

How to pass to the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Can you use Lebesgue theory? The dominated convergence theorem makes it swift.

Comment: Yes we can. But how to bound $f_h(t)=e^{-t} t^{x-1} \frac{t^h-1}{h}$ by a $L^1(0,\infty)$ function?

Comment: You do it locally. For $x_0 < x < x_1$, take $$e^{-t} \cdot (t^{x_1-1} + t^{x_0-1})\cdot \ln t$$ as the dominating function.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see it... we have $0<x<\infty$

Comment: You look at some specific $x$. You pick $x_0,x_1$ so that $0 < x_0 < x < x_1 < +\infty$. Then the above dominates for all $y \in (x_0,x_1)$. Since differentiability is a local property, for the derivative at $x$ it is irrelevant what happens outside $(x_0,x_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you take $t^{x_1-1}+t^{x_0-1}$ ... couldn't we simply leave the term $t^{x-1}$ on its place? One more thing $\frac{t^h-1}{h} \leq \ln t$ is this obvious?

Comment: We need a dominating function in some neighbourhood of $x$. For $t > 1$, the part $t^{x-1}$ of the integrand is increasing in $x$, while for $t < 1$ it is decreasing in $x$. So to get  a dominating function, we need the upper bound of our considered $x$-values for $t > 1$, and the lower bound for $t < 1$. instead of $t^{x_1-1} + t^{x_0-1}$ we could also have used $\max \{ t^{x_1-1}, \, t^{x_0-1}\}$. We don't necessarily have $\frac{t^h-1}{h} \leqslant \lvert\ln t\rvert$, but by the mean value theorem $\frac{t^h-1}{h} = t^\xi\cdot\ln t$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $h$.

Comment: Thus if $x_0 < x+h < x_1$, we are sure that the difference quotient is dominated by our function.

Answer (score 1):

You may combine:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}\log(t)\,dx = -\frac{1}{x^2}\qquad (x>0) $$
with the inequality $0\leq \log(t)\leq\sqrt{t}$ for $t\geq 1$ to prove that the hypothesis of the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) are fulfilled, hence we may differentiate under the integral sign.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x>0$ be fixed. Let $0<\delta<x$. For $|h|<\delta$
$$\Big|\frac{\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)}{h}\Big|= \left|\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x-1} \Big(\frac{t^h-1}{h}\Big)\,dt\right|\leq
\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x-1} \Big|\frac{t^h-1}{h}\Big| dt$$

The convexity of the exponential function a implies that
$$\Big|\frac{t^h-1}{h}\Big|=\Big|\frac{e^{h\log t}-1}{h}\Big|\leq\frac{e^{|h\log t|}-1}{|h|}\leq \frac{e^{\delta|\log t|}-1}{\delta},\qquad t>0.
$$

Observe that
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{\delta|\log t|}-1}{\delta}e^{-t}t^{x-1}\,dt=\frac1\delta\int^1_0t^{x-\delta-1}e^{-t}\,dt+\frac1\delta\int^\infty_1t^{x+\delta-1}e^{-t}-\frac1\delta\Gamma(x)<\infty$$
Hence, by dominated convergence
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)}{h}=\int^\infty_0 t^{x-1}\log(t) e^{-t}\,dt$$