# The right way to find $\frac{d}{ds}\Gamma (s)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gamma-function

I thought up this method to find $\frac{d}{ds}\Gamma (s)$, and I want to know if it is valid. I know that there are other questions about this on MSE but they don't really help me understand whether or not what I do is valid.

Given:
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
Thus:
$$\Gamma'(s)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\Biggl(\int_0^\infty t^{s+h-1}e^{-t}dt-\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt\Biggr)$$
$$\therefore \Gamma'(s)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_0^\infty \Biggl(t^{s+h-1-1}e^{-t}-t^{s-1}e^{-t}\Biggr)dt$$
$$\therefore \Gamma'(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}\biggl(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{t^h-1}{h}\biggr)dt$$
$$\therefore \Gamma'(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}\ln t\;dt$$
Right?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427111

Comment: @Nosrati That doesn't really help me. The answers provided there did not sufficiently help me understand the solution

Comment: I think your solution is right, you just want to pass the limit through the integral.

Comment: @Nosrati Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. You  have demonstrated every step of the proof clearly.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions